# Wordpress Loop target individual item hover

Tags: wordpress, loops, while-loop, hover

Have got stuck on this little problem, managed to get my Wordpress looping with the correct stuff.. and all works fine. the problem i have got is when i try to target the individual item on hover. Ive got my jquery script working but it targets them all.. I know ive got to to change the loop but not sure what im surpose to do.. heres my code anyway. Would be great if you guys could help.. Thanks

Wordpres Loop

```
 <?php $i = 0 ?>
        <?php query_posts('showposts=3'); ?>
        <?php if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if( $i == 3 ) : ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="miniwork">
                            <?php 
                                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                the_post_thumbnail();
                                } 
                            ?>
                            <figcaption><?php the_title(); ?></figcaption>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <?php $i++ ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
```

Jquery Hover

```
 jQuery(".miniwork" ).hover(
  function() {
    jQuery('.miniwork figcaption').addClass('animated tada');
    jQuery('.miniwork figcaption').css('visibility', 'visible');
    var filterVal = 'blur(8px)';
    jQuery('.miniwork img')
      .css('filter',filterVal)
      .css('webkitFilter',filterVal)
      .css('mozFilter',filterVal)
      .css('oFilter',filterVal)
      .css('msFilter',filterVal);
    jQuery('.miniwork figcaption').css('opacity', '0.95')
  }, function() {
    jQuery('.miniwork figcaption').removeClass('animated tada');
    jQuery('.miniwork figcaption').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    jQuery('.miniwork figcaption').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    var filterVal = 'blur(0px)';
    jQuery('.miniwork img')
      .css('filter',filterVal)
      .css('webkitFilter',filterVal)
      .css('mozFilter',filterVal)
      .css('oFilter',filterVal)
      .css('msFilter',filterVal);
      jQuery('.miniwork figcaption').css('opacity', '0')
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting class `"miniwork"` which is being assigned to every div .. you can assign #id to each div too like --

```
<div class="miniwork" id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
    <?php 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
        } 
    ?>
    <figcaption><?php the_title(); ?></figcaption>
</div>
```

Now in jQuery taget '`miniwork#id-of-the-post`'

Comment: Brillant, just what i was looking for.. Thanks